# How do I add carriage return to possible whitespace values in nearley?

Tags: nearley

I'm using [nearley](https://nearley.js.org) but it's failing when running on some CRLF files. Right now I've solved it by commenting the whitespace builtin import and instead redoing it with \r like this:

```
# Whitespace: `_` is optional, `__` is mandatory.
_  -> wschar:* {% function(d) {return null;} %}
__ -> wschar:+ {% function(d) {return null;} %}

wschar -> [ \t\n\r\v\f] {% id %}
```

It would be great to be able to do something like `wschar -> [ \t\n\r\v\f] {% id %}` and base it from the builtin file but doing so creates an infinite loop.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well it was easier than expected. You can always add more definitions to already existing names so adding this line fixes it.

```
wschar -> [\r] {% id %}
```